# Cross thread error, but not using threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, textbox

I keep getting

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'keyholderTxt' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

on various controls on various forms in a project, and I have googled it and found lot's of responses about how to access stuff from various threads, but as far as I know, i'm not using any other threads in my project, and to change the hundreds of possible places in the code would be unmanageable.

It never used to happen, only since I added various code that seems unrelated. I include a sample of places where I get the errors below, but it has occurred in so many places all over the solution.

```
keyholderTxt.Text = "Keyholders Currently In:\r\n \r\n Nibley 1: + keyholders";
```

or this, a better example, as you can see everything that happends from the form loading until the error:

```
      private void Identification_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _Timer.Interval = 1000;
        _Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_Timer_Tick);
        _Timer.Start();

        txtIdentify.Text = string.Empty;
        rightIndex = null;

        SendMessage(Action.SendMessage, "Place your finger on the reader.");

        if (!_sender.OpenReader())
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        if (!_sender.StartCaptureAsync(this.OnCaptured))
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    void _Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.theTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void OnCaptured(CaptureResult captureResult)
    {
       txtIdentify.Clear();
       //other stuff after the cross thread error
    }
```

Can things like not closing datareaders cause this kind of error?

I am using a Windows Forms Application.

Comment: Provided code won't really help us. You need to provide at least a whole method where you assign to a component and then show us where it is called from.

Comment: Are you using a `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: Sometimes you can introduce background threads indirectly, say by using asynchronous methods accessing web services. You get your information callbacks and try to update/bind your UI based on the information, but you don't realize the callback occurred on a background thread.

Comment: I'm not using a BackgroundWorker anywhere. I do a lot of MySQL datareader calls, if they are related.

Comment: Just look at the debugger's Call Stack window.

Comment: call stack provides the following message (from the new code posted above) > CovERTT.exe!CovERTT.Attendance.OnCaptured(DPUruNet.CaptureResult captureResult) Line 62 C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the culprit is this:

```
if (!_sender.StartCaptureAsync(this.OnCaptured))
```

I don't know the API you're using, but based on the name, I think the callback method (`OnCaptured`) is called on a worker thread, not the UI thread. So you need to use Invoke to perform the action on the UI thread:

```
private void OnCaptured(CaptureResult captureResult)
{
   if (InvokeRequired)
   {
       Invoke(new System.Action(() => OnCaptured(captureResult)));
       return;
   }

   txtIdentify.Clear();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I got Error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CovERTT.Attendance.Action' to 'System.Delegate'

Comment: @Wayneio, that's because there is another type in scope with a conflicting name. Try specifying `System.Action` instead of `Action`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, scratch this. I see you're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which, as the comment below mentions, already executes on the UI thread. I was thinking you were using `System.Timers.Timer`.

### Wrong answer

The timer callback is executing on a threadpool thread. You can make it execute on the UI thread by setting the [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx):

```
    _Timer.Interval = 1000;
    _Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_Timer_Tick);
    _Timer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    _Timer.Start();
```

Comment: Apparently this is the WinForms timer, which automatically raises its events on the UI thread, and doesn't have a SynchronizingObject property...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: You're right. `System.Timers.Timer` has an `Elapsed` event, not `Tick`. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like exactly the sort of thing that the OP should be injecting into his/her question frankly...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the thread panel in VS?

Answer (score 1):

The callback from `_Timer` (`void _Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)`)is occurring on a background thread. Make sure you use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (assuming you are using windows forms) if you want the callback to be on the UI thread.

As commenters have suggested. Check the thread window in your debugger to check what thread the exception is occurring on.

Alternatively, for windows forms, try this

```
void _Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.theTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()));
}
```

And for WPF, try this

```
void _Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.theTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()));
}
```

And if `this` is not a control or window and you are in WPF

```
void _Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.theTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: This is WinForms, not WPF (the error message is typical of WinForms). So it's probably the WinForms timer, which automatically raises its events on the UI thread, so it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: 'Probably'. You are probably right. Would love to see it confirmed so that the OP can disregard timer based answers.

Comment: Well, all timers that have a Tick event are UI-related, so they raise their events on the UI tread... So I'm actually pretty sure that my theory is correct ;)